# Import Data to a new table that has a nested table in it

Tags: postgresql, insert, nested, create-table, nested-table

```
INSERT INTO OrderNew (
SalesOrderID,
OrderDate,
DueDate,
ShipDate,
OnlineOrderFlag,
CustomerID,
CreditCardID,
SubTotal,
TaxAmt,
Freight,
TotalDue,
OrderInfo.salesorderdetail,
OrderInfo.orderqty ,
OrderInfo.productid, 
OrderInfo.unitprice,
OrderInfo.unitpricediscount,
OrderInfo.linetotal
)
SELECT h."SalesOrderID" , h."OrderDate", h."DueDate", h."ShipDate", h."OnlineOrderFlag", h."CustomerID", h."CreditCardID", h."SubTotal", h."TaxAmt", h."Freight", h."TotalDue", d."SalesOrderDetailID", d."OrderQty", d."ProductID", d."UnitPrice", d."UnitPriceDiscount", d."LineTotal"
FROM "SalesOrderHeader" h
INNER JOIN "SalesOrderDetail" d ON  d."SalesOrderID" = h."SalesOrderID"
WHERE d."SalesOrderID" = h."SalesOrderID" ;
```

This is the code I use in order to import data from some other tables. 
However, I want the last column to be like a nested table. 
These are the tables that I want to be one. So for one Sales Order ID from the table "SalesOrderHeader" there are a couple or more records with the same Sales Order ID on the table "SalesOrderDetail". So, how can I do it? Using a function?

I don't know if I am an understandable. But I can give more information.

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested table in Postgres. You will need to create a proper one-to-many relationship and then insert in each table separately. Btw: I would highly recommend to not use quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it

Comment: Is there a command like create type xyz as table like in oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create two types in order to shrink a bit the new table which is going to be a combination of the SalesOrderHeader and SalesOrderDetail.

`CREATE TYPE Shipping AS(OrderDate Date,DueDate Date,ShipDate Date);`

`CREATE TYPE ordersdetails AS (details text);`

Then you create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE ordernew ( salesorderid serial NOT NULL, shippinginfo shipping, onlineorderflag integer, customerid serial NOT NULL, creditcardid integer, subtotal real, taxamt real, freight real, totaldue real, orderinfo ordersdetails[]);
```

As for the data, you will just copy the data from the other two tables but writing a right query in order not to create duplicate records. So, the code is below.

```
INSERT INTO OrderNew (
SalesOrderID,
OrderDate,
DueDate,
ShipDate,
OnlineOrderFlag,
CustomerID,CreditCardID,
SubTotal,
TaxAmt,
Freight,
TotalDue,
OrderInfo.salesorderdetail,
OrderInfo.orderqty ,
OrderInfo.productid,
OrderInfo.unitprice,
OrderInfo.unitpricediscount,
OrderInfo.linetotal
)
SELECT h."SalesOrderID" , h."OrderDate", h."DueDate", h."ShipDate", h."OnlineOrderFlag",
h."CustomerID", h."CreditCardID", h."SubTotal", h."TaxAmt", h."Freight", h."TotalDue",
d."SalesOrderDetailID", d."OrderQty", d."ProductID", d."UnitPrice", d."UnitPriceDiscount", d."LineTotal"
FROM "SalesOrderHeader" h
INNER JOIN "SalesOrderDetail" d ON d."SalesOrderID" = h."SalesOrderID"
WHERE d."SalesOrderID" = h."SalesOrderID" ;
```

To simply view the data that you recently inserted just run the following query:

`SELECT orderinfo FROM ordernew;`